# How can I route my Flask Website pages to WordPress pages?

Tags: html, wordpress, flask

I am trying to implement my Flask website to my WordPress website. WordPress website works and my Flask website is available at this moment. For example, I want to put my Flask website homepage to WordPress Homepage. When you press Homepage in WordPress it will show you my Flask Website Homepage.

I am a 31 yo, self-taught developer. Recently, got into an internship. They made me do simple projects and this is the last one. For this last one, I am literally left alone. The good part is that I am at the last stage, which is the payment part and the routing part. I tried to change the URL of the pages in WordPress. For example, `wordpress.com` to `wordpress.com/182.123.123:5000`. When I do this and save. It saves like this: `wordpress.com/182-123-123-2185000`. I do not know how to handle this situation. I am trying to implement a payment system, but they told me not to use any payment stuff from their system. I tried Stripe, but it is not available in my country. If I had Stripe I could just make all my Flask Website with only Flask. Also, I cannot comment or ask someone in Stackoverflow since I do not have any reputation. I need help guys. Be gentle.

Comment: I think I found the solution. It was with a redirect Plugin. I am hoping to redirect every page between WP and Flask websites.